# Is "while" used correctly to connect to ideas?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I want to say that sustainable agriculture can:

1. fix the problem of hunger
2. preserves natural resources

at the same time. Does the following sentence mean the same?

> Only sustainable agriculture and factory farming can fix the problem
> of hunger for the present and next generations while preserving
> natural resources.

Comment: Do x while [verb]ing Y is fine.

Comment: A couple suggestions - 1) usually people say "current and future generations" 2) one typically "solves" a problem rather than "fixing" it. Otherwise, looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of having an answer to the question, as the comments said, yes, this is fine.

As cruthers mentioned, typically one "solves" a problem, but otherwise the sentence looks very good.